# Shopify - capture of Handlebars result not equal in liquid if

Tags: handlebars.js, shopify, liquid

So I am able to capture a handlebars result into a liquid variable and output the value, documentation states it is always a string.  When I test the captured variable against another string variable that should be equal it always returns false.  Not sure why this isn't working, anyone able to lend an assist?

```
{%- raw -%}
{{#items}}
{{#each tags}}{%- endraw -%}
{%- capture strTag -%}{%- raw -%}{{ this }}{%- endraw -%}{%- endcapture -%}

Captured Tag: {{ strTag }} <!-- will spit out the tag, it is being captured -->

{%- assign test_tag = "test tag" -%}
{%- if strTag == test_tag -%} <!-- this never fires as true, but both strTag and test_tag will output as "test tag" --> 
     {{ strTag }} matched {{ test_tag }}
{%- else -%}
     {{ strTag }} did not match {{ test_tag }}  <!-- this is what always returns as "test tag did not match test tag" -->
{%- endif -%}{%- raw -%}
{{/each}}
{/items}}{% endraw %}
```

Comment: try using the strip filter on the `test_tag` variable, it might have extra white spaces that get ignored by the browser. Maybe something like `{% assign test_tag_stripped = test_tag | strip %}`

Comment: tried capturing test_tag and comparing as both captured vars, didn't work.

tried assigning test_tag and  strTag to new vars and doing strip, string, both all three scenarios didn't work.

Comment: another possible explanation would be that `strTag` contains exotic characters different from the ones on your keyboard but visually identical, did you try copy pasting the output value to `test_tag `?

Comment: just tried `str_tag | size` and `test_tag | size`, the `test_tag` returned correctly as 8 however I received in my debugging
 `10 did not match 8
  test tag did not match test tag`, as it loops through the tags the correct text is shown but the size is always 10 for `str_tag`....odd

Comment: found cases also where I could strip down the size to less than the actual visible characters....this just seems broken or rather that captured variables maybe aren't meant to be used like this.  Moved onto a purely Handlebars/JavaScript approach and finished what I needed to get done.